# Winform DataGridview incredibly slow compared to MS Access Grid

Tags: winforms

When I connect to an Oracle Database though ODBC with 100000 rows with MS ACCESS, I can see results instantly and go to the end of the records in 1 seconds.

Doing the same thing with ADO.NET and the Winform Datagridview is incredibly slow it takes dozens of seconds !!!

How to get the same speed as MS Access Gridview ? I can't find any ready-to-use code to do so.

Comment: What's slow? Is the query slow? Is drawing the grid slow? Both?

Comment: Disconnected Mode of ADO.NET is too slow for large datastorage compared to connected mode of ADO.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're binding all rows to the DataGridview at once and it's the drawing that takes a long time.

If all you want is to display data, you can very easily implement Virtual Mode. All it takes is to implement the `CellValueNeeded` event. In Virtual Mode, the grid retreives only the rows needed for display.

It's also possible to implement all the operations a DataGridView can offer but it can take a lot of code.

Take a look at: [Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx)

Comment: That's what I also do with MS Access: I don't have to ask anything else.

I heard already about virtual mode but there's seem to be no code available, and I tried just setting up the GridView Virtual Mode it seems that the Datagrid takes a huge time to setup :(

Why is it becoming so complicated to do what used to be so simple ?

Comment: When you set VirtualMode you will have to do databinding manually. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624.aspx) is an example. Don't know anything about Access but AFAIK there is no simple way of doing this in winforms.

Comment: In access, you just link to an oracle table and set the datasource to its, all this takes 30 seconds with no coding at all and result is very fast when you scroll hundred thousands of records!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks indeed it seems there is no simple way because ADO.NET didn't even include the features of the "old" ADO (I wonder what "progress" is finally :) ):

http://www.udaparts.com/devguide.htm

> ADO.NET is designed to focus the
>   needs of web applications with a
>   completely disconnected model, which
>   requires all of tables data are loaded
>   into an "in-memory" database (a
>   DataSet) before accessing these data.
>   This model works well for web
>   applications, but it does have a
>   number of short comings that make it
>   awkward to use for traditional desktop
>   applications and middle tier
>   components in many cases. In
>   comparison to classical COM ADO/OLEDB
>   technology, ADO.NET has following main
>   short comings listed below:
>
> a).  It is very slow to access a large
>   data table. ADO.NET can manage a small
>   number of data records in disconnected
>   model efficiently. However, it works
>   very slow if the number of data
>   records becomes large because ADO.NET
>   requires loading these records into a
>   DataSet object first and setting
>   relationships among tables. The
>   loading time becomes larger and larger
>   when the number of records becomes
>   larger and larger. It is this reason
>   that leads to a large memory footprint
>   in many cases.
>
> b).  ADO.NET supports sequential
>   forward and read-only server cursor
>   only. It works fine with web
>   applications, but it becomes very
>   awkward with developments for
>   classical desktop and middle tier
>   applications because these
>   applications typically require data
>   accessing mode is able to provide
>   scrollable and updateable server
>   cursors with bookmarks at least.
>   Currently, ADO.NET is not able to
>   provide these features. ADO.NET lacks
>   many fundamental features that the
>   previous COM ADO/OLEDB model provides.
>   This is a huge problem especially for
>   desktop application development.

Their component (http://www.udaparts.com/oledbpronet.htm) seems great except it's not free, hasn't someone developped something similar in Opensource ?

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution
http://www.infralution.com/virtualdata.html

> Is ADO.NETs disconnected model making
>   your simple desktop application seem
>   like a major enterprise programming
>   task?
>
> Infralution's Virtual Data Objects
>   (VDO) may be the solution you have
>   been waiting for.

but still no opensource or free solution ?