# c# very slow populating the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'am populating a datagridview from a datatable.

While populating the columns and rows, I also format it at the same time, this cause the datagridview to load very slowly, is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: Do you have a code example of the formatting. How many data are you loading into the grid? do you use a paged data source or do you load everthing into the grid?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for populating the DatagridView ? Do you have binded the datagridView with the datatable or do you iterate through the datatable and insert the record in the DatagridView  ?

Answer (score 13):

As well as taking care of `AutoSizeColumnsMode`, make sure that individual columns have their `AutoSizeMode` property also set to something other than all cells.

I also found it necessary to use

```
SendMessage(dg.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0); // before

// updates to datagridview here...

SendMessage(dg.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0); // after
```

Comment: Changing the AutoSizeColumnsMode to None before refreshing the datasource, then setting it back to All after the datasource was set dropped the load time for me from several minutes to less than a second.

Answer (score 10):

With this will be datagridview fast as java jtable  :)

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
    {
        Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
    }
}

ExtensionMethods.DoubleBuffered(dataGridView1, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

I was taking about 2-4 minutes to load 1-2k rows.  I changed the auto-resize property and now it's down to seconds, probably 10-20.  I ran this right before my row creation loop to ensure it got all the columns.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in thisGrid.Columns)
{
    c.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could check the property of DataGridView - AutoSizeColumnsMode
I found that if I change the mode from AllCells to DisplayedCells the performance is different.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a datagrid view to display data from dataabse you should always think to use some strategy to limit the results set and show records only when the user really see them. This is called sometime Virtual Mode, or data paging. I got an [example of this strategy for wpf](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/10/11/SomeProgressWithFlyFetch.aspx), but there is something also for winforms. Have a look at this question too: [Winform DataGridview incredibly slow compared to MS Access Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692442/winform-datagridview-incredibly-slow-compared-to-ms-access-grid) I think is related to your problem as well.

Comment: Agreed, when someone talks about the slowness of a datagrid it is usually about the thousands of rows that are being read for displaying just 10 rows. Make sure you're reading the data paginated. (aka: data paging)

Comment: @detay yeah the magic of having a fast grid is not how fast you fill it but avoiding to fill it :D

Answer (score 1):

The rules of a stupid old chap :
- AVOID the DataTable, well known to be inefficicient
- AVOID using preallocation of rows ["Grid".Rowcount + "Grid".AddRange() +..] ( ~5 times slower than "Grid"ADD())
- Consider that a DataGridView is bound to "your screen" : ie. LOAD IT with a few screens of data.
- I applied these simple facts and I can "load" a 'stupid file' of 420 000 rows with 159 columns in 15 sec. ( ~200 MB).

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing in a program where I load 5000 rows with 6 columns and each cell is loaded with the row number just to have some data. I then used Stopwatch to test each approach. I loaded the dataviewgrid, disabled it and loaded it then enabled it, hid it, loaded it, and showed it, and suspendlayout and resumelayout. I found that by hiding it and loading it and then showing it was much faster in my testing.  It took: 
.91 seconds to just load
.91 seconds to suspendLayout, load, resumeLayout
.25 seconds to disable, load and reenable the grid
.19 seconds to hide, load, and show the the grid.

I would agree that you should avoid loading what you dont need to, but thought this test would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case I also had to set 
`DataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DisableResizing`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found worked.  I was building a 52x15 grid with custom cell coloring and it was taking anywhere from 10-20 seconds to generate and display with all the suggestions above not improving performance much.

This change now makes it display in about 1 second along with the double-buffering above.

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

Then after it's done generating the data

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode property, so I suggest this code snippet that incorporates a number of suggestions from other respondents. This has the advantage of not blindly reverting to AutoSize if your grid was not AutoSized some way.:

```
private static void FastLoadDataGrid<T>(DataGridView dgv, IEnumerable<T> objList)
{
    // Cache old values
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode oldAutoSizeCols = dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode;
    DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode oldAutoSizeRows = dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode;
    DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode oldRowHeader = dgv.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode;
    DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode oldCol = dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode;

    dgv.SuspendLayout(); // off for performance 

    // switch off stuff for performance
    dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None; 
    dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None; 
    dgv.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
    dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;

    // flush and load data source 
    dgv.DataSource = null;
    dgv.DataSource = new List<T>(objList); //wrap in sortable bindinglist to allow user to sort via column header click

    // revert back to old values
    dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = oldAutoSizeCols;  
    dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = oldAutoSizeRows; 
    dgv.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = oldRowHeader;
    dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = oldCol;

    dgv.ResumeLayout(false); // turn back on
}
```

A typical call to this procedure is:

```
FastLoadDataGrid(MyDataGridView, MyListOfCustomers);
```

A test of importing 10000 rows with 3 columns and each success displayed in a data grid view went from eight seconds down to three seconds by using my FastLoadDataGrid.

Other suggestions from Microsoft are:
[DataGridView optimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

A totally different approach that could done as well or instead of is to use virtualization. Turn on VirtualMode = true. But this potentially requires refactoring of the data bound events. See:
[DataGridView Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score -1):

I have a fairly good performance of `DataGridView`. Adding several hundred rows takes about 200ms. Here's what I do:

`virtual = true`  -- using a **virtualized data grid** view seems to make the whole process faster. Just remember to properly implement `logViewGrid_CellValueNeeded`.

Another thing to do is to temporarily disable layout events when adding data to bound list. Try to do:

```
logViewGrid.SuspendLayout();
// add data, perform some operations on grid view
logViewGrid.ResumeLayout(false);
```

I also had a problem with **slow rows coloring**; my method for doing that was setting each cells' style separately, like this:

```
gridViewInstance.Rows[currentRow].Cells[cellIndex].Style.BackColor = val;
```

Instead, I went for:

```
gridViewInstance.Rows[currentRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = val;
```

Which, for 30 columns, gave me significant speed increase in that part of the code.